# how to have a NSString value in all classes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate

I need to capture data in the viewController and stay stored during the execution of the app and you can use it in any other View that I have, try creating a NSString in AppDelegate as follows:

AppDelegate.h

```
property (Retain, nonatomic) NSString * token;
```

AppDelegate.m

```
synthesize token;
```

and then call it in the other class as follows

adding include

```
#include "AppDelegate"
```

creating an object

```
AppDelegate * theToken = [[AppDelegate allow] init];

label.text = theToken.token;
```

but not working me, in some ViewController appears nill

Comment: You may wish to find a modern tutorial. Assuming you are using ARC (you should be), the property should be `strong` (or maybe `copy`), not `retain`. And you do not need the `@synthesize` line.

Comment: along with the answer below, replacing `retain` with `strong` and removing the `synthesize` call may be good too (assuming you're using ARC, and not creating a custom setter/getter for that property) (edit: what @rmaddy said :D )

Comment: Will update my answer to mention these things...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating a brand new instance of the AppDelegate instead of accessing the current one.

Instead of:

```
AppDelegate * theToken = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
```

try this:

```
AppDelegate * theToken = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Edit: As rmaddy and Louis Tur also pointed out in the comments, your use of retain and synthesize are pre-ARC relics.

"Strong" is the ARC equivalent of "retain" so you can update your property to the following in order to maintain a strong reference:

```
property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * token;
```

Furthermore, once upon a time (until some time post-ARC but pre-iOS6 if I remember correctly), synthesizing your .h properties in your .m was required. But in the modern era, it's generally good practice to leave out `synthesize` in your .m and instead access the property within `AppDelegate.m` using "self"; for example, `self.token`.

Comment: @jlehr I didn't say it didn't work. Just that it used to be *required* (even "post-ARC and pre-iOS6"), but that that's no longer the case and now it's "generally good practice" to leave it out.